# Backbone using el that is not yet created?

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js

I'm building a single web page app using Backbone.

My master views depends on template that will replace the body part of my page based on the URL, but since I must provide an "el" for that view, I wanted it to be the template itself, that would be inserted in the DOM in the "render" or "initialize" method.

But when I call new MyMasterView, the el is undefined since it isn't present in the DOM at instantiation.

How can I do ?

The only fix I found is to set the el to the existing DOM where I replace the content, and call a `.remove().append(the_template)` in the render, but I'm not sure it's the best way.

Comment: Do you have any example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can consider a scenario where you have the following div in the DOM

```
<div id="existing">

</div>
```

This div can be any other element where you wanted to insert the html generated by your view.

Suppose, you have following template,

```
<div id="inside_template">
  <!-- content of the template goes here -->
</div>
```

You can specify `existing` as an `el` for the view as its already present in the div. The only problem you will have is, if its some tag like `body` or something, then if you remove it from the view while clearing the view (to prevent memory leaks), it will delete the tag from the dom which might not be desired.

A solution to that could be, specify `existing` as `el`, render view's html in that `el` and after that call [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) right after appending the template html to the DOM like,

```
render : function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template());
  this.setElement("#inside_template");

  // another render method content
}
```

What this will do is, it will change the `el` for the view from `existing` (or any other DOM element) to `inside_template`. So while removing the `el`, `inside_template` element will be removed, keeping `existing` element as it is in the DOM.

Comment: how great! I didn't knew about setElement! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried leaving `el` null and just setting `tagName`? If you do that, [_ensureElement](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-159) will create a new detached DOM node for your view's element. You should be able to render a DOM fragment detached from the page's DOM and then external code can put that element into place using `append` or perhaps something like jQuery's `replaceWith`.